# Generating a Django Model that can have multiple values in one field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, seeding, django-fixtures

I am trying to generate a Django model that can handle multiple values in a single field. As such, when the first field is queried through a view, a user should select a value for the second field through a select box.

To give a background of the problem, my seeding fixture looks like this...

```
[
  {
    "model":"myapp.location",
    "pk":1,
    "fields":{
      "county": "countyname",
      "places":{
        "name": "placename",
        "name": "placename",
        "name": "placename",
        "name": "placename",
        "name": "placename"
      }
    }
}
]
```

In the above scenario, location is the intended name of my model. Now, through a form, I want a user to be presented with 'countynames'. Upon selecting a countyname, the user should be presented with 'placenames' in the selected county for them to choose.

I have tried the following format for the model...

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    places = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=places.name)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.countyname
```

Now, I know that the error that is thrown, ('places' is not defined), is warranted. I was asking whether there is a way to define it (places), as it is in the fixture, or if anyone has a better implementation for such a model... any alternative way is welcome and appreciated as I can't think of anything at this point.

Comment: Sounds like you need a separate Place model connected via a ForeignKey.

Comment: Is that seeding fixture a fixed constraint? Because it may need to change in order to solve your problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I would work. However, I meant to create a DRY dataset that I can reuse in my later projects. I think I have found a solution that I am posting in the next few minutes.

Comment: @DanielHolmes True. I have amended the fixture to fit a Model that works.. I am posting it in a few... Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after fiddling with two models and foreign keys as suggested in the comments above, I decided to amend the model, which also led to changing the fixture. I read about ArrayFields in Postgres + Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/). I amended the field 'places' to be an ArrayField as shown:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Location(models.Model):
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    places = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.county
```

Next, it was just a matter of changing the JSON fixture to:

```
[
  {
    "model":"myapp.location",
    "pk":1,
    "fields":{
      "county": "countyname",
      "places":["placename","placename","placename","placename"]
    }
  }
]
```

After running `python manage.py loaddata fixturename.json` , 
it worked and the DB was seeded!